# JSON returning [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to return the JSON data from the specified URL but when the alert pops up it just shows [object Object] (I realize the object object is not in fact an error). **I would like to spit out the position name and other fields in the alert**. How do I do this?

Here is an example of the JSON I am looking at (the full file has about 30 postings)

```
[
  {
    "m_id": 473644,
    "m_positionName": "Application Monitoring Software Engineer",
    "m_positionLocations": [
      {}
    ],
    "m_active": true,
    "m_description": "Job Responsibilities:\r\n\r\n-Create world class application monitoring tools and dashboards for our health care applications\r\n\r\n-Develop business rules to pro actively identify and re-mediate system-level issues before they occur.\r\n\r\n-Create business intelligence reports for internal and external use as a supplement to software products.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nJob Requirements:\r\n\r\n-BS or MS Degree in computer science or any engineering discipline.\r\n-4+ years of experience with Java (or other object-oriented programming language).\r\n-Experience in SQL, Struts, Hibernate, Spring, Eclipse, JSP, JavaScript.\r\n-Highly motivated and self-driven personality.\r\n-Excellent interpersonal and leadership skills.\r\n-A vision for the future and a desire to make a difference.\r\n-Experience with Maven, Tomcat, PostgreSql, Jasper Reports,",
    "m_postedDate": "Jun 29, 2012 9:17:19 AM",
    "m_closingDate": "Jun 29, 2013 12:00:00 AM"
  }
]
```

And here is the script I am using.

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: '/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/jobopenings.json',
 async: false,
 beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
 },
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
```

Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of the `alert`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function(data)
{
  var _len = data.length;
  , post, i;

  for (i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
    //debugger
    post = data[i];
    alert("m_positionName is "+ post. m_positionName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now we're cooking. This spits out every position thank you!

Comment: Now if I wanted to append this data to the body rather than alert it what would I write. I came up with this but its not working.

`('<li>' + "m_positionName is " + post.m_positionName + '</li>').appendTo('body');`

Comment: @user1324700
`success: function(data)
{
  var _len = data.length;
  , $span = $('<span>')
  , post, i;

  for (i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
    //debugger
    post = data[i];
    $span.html("m_positionName is "+ post. m_positionName).appendTo('body');
    alert("m_positionName is "+ post. m_positionName);
  }
}`

Answer (score 20):

You could always turn the object into a string and alert that.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: That does spit out the data in the object but I want to specifically spit out the m_description field into some html say an **li**

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery receive a json, jQuery automatically convert it to a javascript object. So `data` just contains your object ready to be used.
If you want to access to the original text of the response, you can do this :

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

Comment: This does spit out the raw text but I want to spit out 

`m_positionName` , `m_description` and others