# Iterating through JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read schedule data from a JSON file called `js/schedule.json` which looks like:

```
[
{"date":"12/06/2014","day":"Thursday","kick-off":"21:00","team1":"Brazil","team2":"Croatia","group":"A","stage":"group stages","broadcaster":"ITV"},
{"date":"13/06/2014","day":"Friday","kick-off":"17:00","team1":"Mexico","team2":"Cameroon","group":"A","stage":"group stages","broadcaster":"ITV"}

...    
]
```

I want to iterate through each item in the JSON object and only return the match fixture where the "date" matches a previously set variable called: `today`.

The jQuery I'm using is the following:

```
function getArray(){
    return $.getJSON('js/schedule.json');
}

getArray().done( function(json) {
    console.log(json); // show the json data in console
    var _len = json.length;
    var fixture;


    //loop through json and match today's date with match-date
    for (var i in json) {
        fixture = json[i];
        if (fixture.date == today) {
            //print out today's schedule here
            console.log(fixture.team1 + " Vs. " + fixture.team2);
        }
    }

});
```

However, what I get as an output in the Console is 
`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`,  there are 7 items in the object so this is the correct amount for the time being, however I can't get the console to show the `fixture.team1 + fixture.team2`

I've checked various posts which have similar problems such as [JSON returning [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456610/json-returning-object-object) but these don't quite fix it.

Any help would be fantastic. Cheers!

**As pointed out the problem here was with the value of `today` not matching the value in the `date`. After adding a preceding "0" to months/days < 10 the code worked.**

Comment: What is the value of `today` exactly ? Seems to me that your `date` field has a simple string value, so if your `today` variable is a Javascript date, you will need to parse it accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572), though that is probably not the reason for your problem

Comment: So it seems there's no issue with anything except for performing the date comparison. As such, you should ask specifically about that issue, or rather search for the answer first.

Comment: @dubblebee Cookie monster is totally right.  Comment out if (fixture.date == today) {} and  console.log(fixture.team1 + " Vs. " + fixture.team2); displays exactly what you expect. You need to handle your dates.  See doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: @wrousseau for test purposes `today` is set to "12/6/2014". Is the omission of a leading 0 in "/6/" is causing the data mismatch?

Comment: @Bart OK Yes you are correct. That now displays what I'm expecting , so I need to correct my date handling. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

is an output of

```
console.log(json); // show the json data in console
```

You have never got output of

```
console.log(fixture.team1 + " Vs. " + fixture.team2);
```

because your condition in `if-condition` is always `false` in your example. So, you should specify properly value for `today` variable.

If you want to log `json` object, you can use `JSON.stringify` function

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like you are right, as @cookie monster above said also.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `for ... in` when you want a normal for loop (given your data is an array of objects, not an object with a lot of unknown properties/keys). With that said, try something like:

```
getArray().done(function(json){
    // ...

    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
       var o = json[i]; // {"date":"12/06/2014","day":"Tursday",...}
       // now perform a check against `o['date']` or `o.date` and return the
       // matching result
    }
});
```

Comment: Your way of iterating is better, but I'm not seeing how it addresses the issue in the question. He's already performing a check against the `.date` property.